# “ImportError: No module named boto3” on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-import, boto3, importerror

I am trying a deployment script, which will need to import boto3, when I run the script, it give me error message:

```
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

then I ran:

```
pip install boto3
```

it returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.228)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from boto3) (0.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 in /Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from boto3) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.228 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3) (1.12.228)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils<0.16,>=0.10 in /Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.228->boto3) (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.228->boto3) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version >= "3.4" in /Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.228->boto3) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7"->botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.228->boto3) (1.12.0)
```

I ran `pip3 install boto3`, still it gave the same output as above.

then I ran the deployment script, the same errors with complaining

```
ImportError: No module named boto3
```

Any ideas where goes wrong?

I'm using mac 10.14.6 version.

Comment: how are you running the script

Comment: Please check which interpreter is running your script by adding `print(sys.executable)` and `print(sys.path)` before the `boto3` import. Also, is there more to the traceback?

Comment: I run deployment script with parameters, locally. added traceback, but no clue...

Comment: What is your directory tree structure?

Answer (score 2):

> Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.228)
>   Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from boto3) (0.9.4)

Make sure that `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and `/Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages` are in the path.

Use the below code to `temporarily` append it to the path.:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages')
print(sys.path)

import boto3
```

Comment: Check if "/Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages" is in the path? Because urllib3 is installed there. From: "Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version >= "3.4" in /Users/xiaoyiliu/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.228->boto3) (1.25.3)".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed your package with the pip associated with a particular python, use:

`python -m pip install <pkg>`

instead of:

`pip install <pkg>`